# Let receive 0 but not invalid values

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a input that i want to recive any number (dont matter if its negative, float, long) i code this to now allow null, undefined or empty values, but if I enter 0 it is read as empty

```
const inputElement = Number(document.getElementById("inputNumber").value);
  if (!inputElement) {
    window.alert("Insira um valor válido");
    return;
  }
```

i already tried this but dont work

```
if (!inputElement && inputElement != 0){
  window.alert("Insira um valor válido");
  return;
 }
```

Does anyone know how to differentiate 0 from empty or vice versa?

Comment: `i already tried this but nothing changed` - odd, seeing as that actually does what you'd expect - of course, I may be misunderstanding what you want ... and `Number("")` is zero of course - perhaps you should check `document.getElementById("inputNumber").value.length` to see if it's empty

Comment: yes, I can receive 0 on this way, but if I click on the submit button without any value, I also receive 0, which I don't want

Comment: because as I said `Number("")` IS zero - you'll want to check the length of the actual input of course

Comment: `!inputElement && inputElement != 0` should be `!inputElement || Number(inputElement) == 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (inputElement.length && !isNaN(+inputElement) && inputElement !== null)
```

This checks for string length, possible null value, and non-numeric input. The plus sign casts inputElement to number.